# Is this result valid only for a non-rotating system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, reference-frames, differential-geometry, geodesics

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6539) paper "*Quantum Raychaudhuri equation*" by S.Das.

In this paper, the author derives a quantum version of the Raychaudhuri equation which has nice implication on the focussing theorem.

It seems that it is valid only for non-rotating spacetimes: is it correct?

Has it been extended also to the rotating case?

Comment: Have you seen the critique of this paper in [arXiv:1606.04738](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04738)?

Comment: @A.V.S. No thanks for showing me it